# What function can i use for my excel example?

Tags: excel, function, vlookup

I have the next situation:

Column A - represent my values.

Column B,C,D - are values resulted from an vlookup formula.
What I need is:

I need to check if a value from A1 is found in B1 or C1 or D1 and if value is TRUE, i want to return A1 value in E1.

I tried with many functions but nothing helped me. My last try is with multiple vlookup functions but it doesn't work...

=VLOOKUP($A2,CHOOSE({1,2,3},$C$2:$C94319&$D$2:$D$94319&$E$2:$E$94319,$A$2:$A$94319),1,0)

Please Help me!
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "and if value is TRUE"?

Comment: How about =Iferror(If(Or(A1=B1,A1=B1,A1=B1),A1,""),"")

Comment: Pete! Your formula should be : lferror(If(Or(A1=B1,A1=C1,A1=D1),A1,""),"")   No ?

Comment: If value is TRUE, i mean if any of those interrogation (A1=B1,A1=C1,A1=D1) is correct, then in E1 return value A1.
i have 90k rows. i want for each line from A column to interrogete 3 values. B,C,D. If any of thoose is equal with A, then return A in column E.

I hope that u can understant me, i'm not so good at english :D

Comment: i tested the formula and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formula that you can use (assuming your data starts from row 1):

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH("*" & A1 & "*",B1:D1,0),FALSE), A1,"Not Found")
```

[image]